# severe OPERA problem loading google image search json with jquery..(

Tags: json, image, opera

my code works fine with IE8, Chrome, FireFox, but **DOESN't** in last Opera 11.5, 11.51

```
 <script>

$.ajax({
    url:"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=barack%20obama&key=ABQIAAAA0WIba2EsveoBgNmpFF4VPBT_f2PMeCqK40xCWP-HTF5Ln8EjvhRvRnHj8jasieBYBypbUK53aU5vOA&mgsz=medium",
    dataType:"jsonp",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){

    for (var i = 0; i < data.responseData.results.length; i++){

     $('#imago').append('<img src="' + data.responseData.results[i].tbUrl + '">' + '<br>');

    }



    }

});


</script>

<div id="imago"></div>
```

**noticed paradox**: if I add a line, alerting data.responseData.results[i].tbUrl before appending received tbUrl images, it becomes working in Opera too...

here's example: http://saitostroi.by/im.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the DIV you want to insert results into *above* the script that does the Ajax query. The reason is that Opera doesn't continue parsing (and thus doesn't see the DIV) when jQuery appends a script to the document, until that script is done loading.